# Delete Long Text Box

Tags: nodes

I have a Node Content Type that has an "unlimited" number of Long text boxes allowed.  I have created one-too-many text ![enter image description here][1]boxes and cant seem to find a way to delete them.

Here is a link to what I am talking about

http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20120730-gpz3-42kb.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually "Delete" the extra values, you can simply leave the extra boxes empty and they will be ignored when you save the content.